# How do I create a Sharepoint hosted app for office 365 in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I've setup Visual Studio 2013 RC and a Office 365 developer site. I can create an app using Nappa and open it in VS from there. But if I create a Sharepoint hosted app project in VS and point it to the url of my developersite it get stuck on "communicating with sharepoint" for a long while and then asks if I want to set the project in "offline mode", obviously I click "no" and then visual studio hangs.

Comment: Did you ever get any answers to your question? I have the same problem :( Edit: I solved the problem. I made two changes. Not sure which one of them actually was the solution. 1. Changed the url to http**s**://mydomain.sharepoint.com.
2. Added an app catalog to my developer site. This can be done in the SharePoint admin section (mydomain-admin.sharepoint.com) right under the apps section (first option in the right hand menu). I would guess the only real problem was the https protocol but since I didnt try them out one by one I chose to post both as a possible solution.

Comment: Is this a product bug, anyone know?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Any solution.
I put https://

Comment: @asimnadeem Same here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not obvious. You need to prefix the url of the site with httpS:// and not http://.

Comment: This may be *one* answer. But I'm facing the same problem as described above and I use HTTPs. So there are other reasons for the communication to fail aswell..

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need both the **https** and an **app catalog** on your office 365 (SharePoint Online) site to resolve the "Connecting to SharePoint" issue in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

1 fault in the URL will give you the message.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer with some brief description.