# can't connect to sharepoint online from visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-online

I'm new to SharePoint and have just set up a demo developer site. When I try to run my app in Visual studio 2013, it prompts me to log in to Office 365 for which I do have account. But once I've filled in my credentials, it just pops up with "Something went wrong".

I definitely have the correct details, and the correct rights.

I just cannot find the reason why it won't let me log in, is the problem maybe on the Microsoft side? But if so, why can I log in through IE?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So it turns out that somewhere along the line my colleague had infact removed my privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have the connection correct as its asking for credentials also could you check to see if your a site collection admin for the given site your trying to access?

> To browse a SharePoint site, you must be an administrator of the
>   SharePoint site collection, and you must be running Visual Studio as
>   an administrator of the local computer. Otherwise, the site appears in
>   Server Explorer, but you can't expand its node. To verify whether you
>   are an administrator of the site collection, open the site in a web
>   browser, open the Site Actions menu, choose Site Permissions, and
>   then, on the Permissions: Team Site page, choose the Site Collection
>   Administrators command from the Manage group on the ribbon. Your name
>   will appear in the text box if you are a site collection
>   administrator. If the Site Collection Administrators command doesn't
>   appear in the Manage group on the ribbon, you aren't an administrator
>   for the site collection, and you must obtain the appropriate
>   permissions from the site administrator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231586.aspx

also like to know when you say app what are you refering to? sharepoint app or an application?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/360f4100-56be-4662-b66f-5198f02874c5/error-while-opening-a-sharepoint-2013-app?forum=appsforsharepoint

Answer (score 1):

Are you 100% sure you are using the HTTPS protocol? I had a similar issue and it took a good while until I realized what I was doing.

[Possible duplicate](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77126/how-do-i-create-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-for-office-365-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you just use the wrong url. Try to take a look on the url side.

Use https://*yourname*.sharepoint.com and choose "sharepoint hosted" for first steps.

Make sure you got the right permissions.

Comment: that was done correctly. I have checked it now again and all seems to be in order

Comment: How old is the SP Dev site? Is it just created a few hours ago?

Comment: It's about a week old. And was created by someone else who will also make use of it. I'm thinking maybe he accidently took me off or something... not sure if that is it...

Comment: Steps I would suggest to get near a solution:
- make sure that you got all rights you could get e.g. global admin
- you can later strap permissions again
- if you got an msdn subscription, you can also get your own office 365 dev edition, just take a look to your msdn benefits. see if it is working there, if it is, get your colleague a kick ;)